# Flutter app PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My flutter app, which was able to build for many months, apparently  can't build anymore, and I didn't make any build related changes.

**How I build my app:**

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi prod -t lib/main.dart  --no-sound-null-safety
```

**Where do i build my app:**

1. Inside Android Emulator terminal
2. In macos terminal

**Error log**

```
[01:14:40]: ▸ FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[01:14:40]: ▸ * What went wrong:
[01:14:40]: ▸ Execution failed for task ':amplify_api_android:mergeReleaseResources'.
[01:14:40]: ▸ > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':amplify_api_android:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
[01:14:40]: ▸ > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-3ad69d7be3a7231aab5525db322fc699f098315f.
[01:14:40]: ▸ Required by:
[01:14:40]: ▸ project :amplify_api_android
[01:14:40]: ▸ project :amplify_api_android > project :amplify_core
[01:14:40]: ▸ > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-3ad69d7be3a7231aab5525db322fc699f098315f.
[01:14:40]: ▸ > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_release/1.0.0-3ad69d7be3a7231aab5525db322fc699f098315f/flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-3ad69d7be3a7231aab5525db322fc699f098315f.pom'.
[01:14:40]: ▸ > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_release/1.0.0-3ad69d7be3a7231aab5525db322fc699f098315f/flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-3ad69d7be3a7231aab5525db322fc699f098315f.pom'.
[01:14:40]: ▸ > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[01:14:40]: ▸ * Try:
[01:14:40]: ▸ Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[01:14:40]: ▸ * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[01:14:40]: ▸ BUILD FAILED in 32s
```

It keeps on throwing `> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

But this file, i'm able to download when I run thru the browser.

**What I've done so far**

1. Invalidated android studio cache
2. Delete flutter cache
3. flutter clean && flutter pub get
4. flutter channel stable && flutter clean && flutter pub get

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying to build my app on a machine connected to the enterprise VPN - disconnecting from the vpn solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try running `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`, then retrying the build.

Comment: tried multiple times.. nothings working

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by running below command, but I don't understand why. Just sharing in case someone also encountered the same issue.

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the network that you are connected to use a personal hotspot or change your WIFI.